# PHPstorm 6.03: changing editor font and size and use of tab key

Tags: php, web-applications, phpstorm

I just downloaded PHP storm 6.03 and have been trying to change the editor font size (code view font size and font) but to no avail. Is this a bug or what?
the tab could also be handy if it could break out of "",'',() {}. This feature is found in aptana where after typing the {some text here}, the user hits the tab key and leaves both braces. a handy trick could also help. Thanks

Comment: Follow link : http://superuser.com/questions/586142/webstorm-phpstorm-select-specific-font-from-a-font-family

Save Scheme name and change font size

Answer (score 3):

1. `Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | Font`
   (**P.S.** Settings screen has **search** functionality -- top left corner -- you should try it)
2. Not currently available. Watch this ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74666

Comment: `ctrl+alt+s` to open `settings` or open from `menu > settings`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but I tried in version 8 and font was grayed out, so I found under settings IDE Setting > Editor. On the right side under "Mouse" I checked the "Change font size (Zoom) with ctrl+Mouse Wheel. Hit ok, and used my ctrl + mouse wheel to change my font...

EDIT: Ok so here is how I did it. I had to go to Settings then IDE Settings and under that Colors and Fonts (don't expand), then on the right side saved as the default scheme and then I was able to change font size...

Basically had to make my own Scheme, copy existing one... works now...